# Incorrect string value - JOOQ - Java

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jooq

I am trying to upload csv into my mysql db using jooq how ever i am getting following error.I tried various solutions suggested on net but cant fix it

```
Error: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into `Test`.`testtable` <mydata> Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD15 ...' for column 'colum_Name' at row 1
```

How I am uploading csv to jooq

```
create.loadInto(Tables.TableName)
                .onErrorIgnore()
                .loadCSV(new File("/tmp/uploaded-files/" + fileName), "UTF-8").<fields>.execute();
```

I ensure file is in utf-8 however when ever there is UTF-8 character record is failing to save in DB and throwing above error.I ensured using

```
file -i <filename>
```

front end ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: fileUploadUrl,
    data: dataforFileUpload,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        alert(message);
        console.log("upload done "+ new Date());

    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", e.responseText);
        alert("ERROR : "+  e.responseText);

    }
});
```

I am getting file from my front end reading it via java rest

```
InputStream inputStream = listingFilePart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);
```

and writing file recursively  in local system before passing to  jooq

```
PrintWriter fop = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I set my DB to accept utf-8 and I verified the same

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.Issue is on ajax call.
I need to send charset  with `enctype` like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8',
    url: fileUploadUrl,
    data: dataforFileUpload,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        alert(message);
        console.log("upload done "+ new Date());

    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", e.responseText);
        alert("ERROR : "+  e.responseText);

    }
});
```